# reading a key from iCloud is nil for some devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

I have stored a key on iCloud and I am reading on devices (not simulator) using

```
NSString *IDicloud;

NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *store = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
if (store) {
    IDicloud = [store objectForKey:@"UUID"];
}
```

when I read the key on the same device used to create and store it on iCloud, the value reads  correctly but when I try to read the same key on another device, I get nil. All devices are using the same AppStore ID, all running iOS 6 and all with iCloud configured and working. Imagining this could be a propagation delay I waited 24h and tried again. The problem persisted.

The entitlements are set like this

```
use entitlements file = myAppName
key-value store = use store with identifier com.myCompany.myAppName
ubiquity containers = com.myCompany.myAppName
keychain groups = com.myCompany.myAppName
```

Why is this happening?

NOTE: I suspect the values are being stored locally but not updated to iCloud. How can I check that?

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not a lot of great tools to test. You might consider setting up a proxy to see what traffic your device is sending. Have you considered calling the 'synchronize' method? It doesn't force an iCloud sync but it does give it a hint that it might want to sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I found [this solution](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/68488#post-224423) and it worked!!!! The solution to this problem is to delete all iCloud accounts from all devices you are testing the app and create them again!